# YouTube API v3 Request still counting after stopped

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a YouTube API Key, and I was testing it out when I started watching my [requests] through the `dashboard?project=myproject-111111&duration=PT1H`

The issue is this. I stopped using the key about 15 minutes ago, and that blasted thing is STILL counting. Since I stopped using it, it has gone from 
9,875 -to- 39,978 (And still counting)
Why would this be still counting for? The key is NOT being used, but its counting. 
You are allowed 1 million requests per 24 hour day. And at this rate, I will be there in no time flat.
I have tried to find an active Forum for the YouTube API, and there is none. The only ones I found had their last post in 2012 and 2014.
Any idea's why this thing is still counting? (46,333)

> **Updated** 10:47 pm EST: On the [Quotas] page. It is over 300,000+ and counting. This is a blasted joke. I reported it in as a bug, but the bug reporting page, is so full of SPAM, that it makes you wonder on rather they are going to check it regularly or not.
>
> **Updated** 10:51 pm EST: It finally stopped. Conflicting count returns are coming in from the different pages.
> 118,762 on the dashboard
> 415,489 on the YouTube Quotas page.
> I went to the YouTube Developers Twitter page and tweeted to them about the issue, and am awaiting a reply back.
> I will post here, once I get a reply back.
> Is this a BUG?
> Or, do other issue?

CodingEE

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I was looking at. As quota is eaten up by api calls that the site is not actually making.

This is unfortunately something for Google to fix. I did send a request to look into it, but no reply.

The cause is "BOTS". They will search, index and run the page affectively to index and rate it. As such, the will incur api usage.
This can be reduced in a few ways.

1: If in testing stage, and you do not use the online version too often apart from testing updates to code, then you can remove the api key from the code while not testing.

2: If it is live and running, but you wish to stop the bots eating the quota, then in your Google dashboard, block the bots.

This will however stop indexing. So I would recommend "trying" to limit them and how often they inex.

Aside from that, we need to get Google to  (if possible) not use quota for bots.

Comment: The issue with that scenario is that the site is in development inside of Visual Studio. So, when I stop the Process and close out of the page. It has stopped. There are no calls, and no bots to cause false "Request".

Comment: I do not use Visual Studio, so I can not say definitively what is happening on your system. However, it stands to reason, something is still running. As well as your system is still connected to the net. So I would say to inspect your settings and do a "Visual Studio" question on connection issues that might have relevance to your setup. If it is still happening after the system is off/disconnected, then you have something online still running that is linked to your development process.

Comment: I THINK that I might have figured it out. I did a large query against the YouTube API. And I ran that same Query today and I monitored it. I stopped the Query about 1/2 way through. However. After I stopped the process on the page and stopped Visual Studio. I notice that it still inserted records into the database for about another 5 minutes. So. It looks like it is finishing up the Query. And there is no way to stop it, that I can find. So, it looks like that is the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Depending on the query, you can put a conditional statement in the loop that will exit if it is met. Aside from that, I am not sure at the moment.